ViewChild change detection throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
I have custom Angular Component modal-component that serves as a proxy for MatModalDialog with ngTemplateOutlet as body for mat-dialog-content.
<mat-dialog-content class="modal-dialog-medium">
    <ng-container *ngIf="dialogData.ngTemplateOutlet" [ngTemplateOutlet]="dialogData.ngTemplateOutlet"></ng-container>
</mat-dialog-content>

I also have custom Angular Component form-component for forms  - input some config of the form and controls.
This form-component has getter method valid that returns boolean that states whether the formGroup is valid or not.
The submit button is outside of form-component - inside mat-dialog-actions and this button needs to be disabled based on whether the form is valid or not. This is ensured by callback in injected MAT_DIALOG_DATA
//this.matDialog.open(ModalComponent, {data: ....
ngTemplateOutlet: this.formTemplate,
okButtonDisabled: () => !this.formComponent?.valid

<!-- modal-component -->
<button-component (click)="dialogData.okButtonAction && dialogData.okButtonAction()"
               [disabled]="dialogData.okButtonDisabled && dialogData.okButtonDisabled()"
               [text]="dialogData.okButtonText || 'OK'"></button-component>

As i said, the body of modal-component is ngTemplateOutlet, so my template looks something like this:
<ng-template #formTemplate>
  <form-component *ngIf="formFields" [config]="formConfig"
           [fields]="formFields" #formComponent (onSubmit)="submit()"></form-component>
</ng-template>

References to the elements:
@ViewChild('formTemplate') formTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('formComponent') formComponent: FormComponent;

When i call this.matDialog.open(...), the ngTemplateOutlet renders into the view and FormComponent.valid returns false. Right after the view is rendered, FormComponent.formGroup is initialized and FormComponent.valid becomes true. This triggers Expression has changed after it was checked on [disabled].
I've encountered this error a few times past these days and I studied change detection and this error countless times trying to figure out how can i implement a clean solution that does not trigger this error, but i haven't been able to (I've fixed 2 similar errors by calling change detection in ngAfterContentChecked, but I can't fix it here and i frankly don't like it).
Am I missing something? Or am I just doing this wrong?

You could easily fix this using signals, if you have the right version of angular. Which version are you using?

sorry for not clarifying, I am using angular 13
